# ssh config - do not execute remote command

Tags: ssh

I would like to setup one of the SSH connections in my `ssh_config` file to use the `-N` ssh flag. I can't find any matching config keyword for this parameter. I'm using the connection for port forwarding only and I would like it to use `-N` every time I execute `ssh host`. I'm using mosh for the interactive shell.

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

Answer (score 5):

Being a fairly prominent result in Google, this is still worth answering 11 years later:

```
Host example
    HostName     example.com
    SessionType  none
```

`SessionType` was introduced in [**OpenSSH 8.7**, released in **2021-08-20**](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7), in [this commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/eda8909d1b0a85b9c3804a04d03ec6738fd9dc7f):

> add a `SessionType` directive to `ssh_config`, allowing the configuration file to offer equivalent control to the `-N` (no session) and `-s` (subsystem) command-line flags.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer! FWIW, it was me who fixed this issue, provided a patch to OpenSSH, went though several review rounds, eagerly awaited the Debian package ... but finally forgot to add it in this ServerFault question as an answer. See also: https://njh.eu/openssh

Comment: @vog: Nice! Well done, and thank you for that patch, it's is very handy! No more aliasing `ssh -nNT` :)

Comment: @vog btw, what software you used for the blogger-like at njh.eu ? I liked its simplicity, and currently looking for self-hosting blogger apps to my homelab)

Comment: MestreLion: It is a simple, hand-written XSLT script. Feel free to approach me via email if you want to know more.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly sure you can't do that and like you I can't find a way of doing it in the manner that you want. If typing `ssh -N host` doesn't appeal then you could always try creating an alias if mosh supports it.

Time passes ... see below https://serverfault.com/a/1152274/9517

Comment: Yeah thanks, my plan was to use the ssh config together with the ssh workflow for Alfred (OS X). That would allow me to type ssh vps01 in Alfred and have it launch a terminal window for forwarding without the shell. Guess I'll have to solve it some other way then :)

Comment: @DanielJohansson: I don't know anything about mosh but in bash you could alias it.

Comment: This answer is almost 3 years old. Has anything changed in the meantime?

Comment: @vog yes it did, in 2021, with `SessionType`. See my answer below.

Comment: @MestreLion Hehe, well, I know, because it was myself adding that feature to OpenSSH. ;-)  See also: https://njh.eu/openssh

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about mosh, but for the OpenSSH client you can specify a ProxyCommand in the config file. The relevant entry for hostname foobar.baz.edu (my favorite university) and dynamic forwarding of port 9999 would be:

```
Host FooBar
   HostName foobar.baz.edu
   ProxyCommand ssh -ND 9999 %h
```

Comment: This is not really relevant to the question. `-N` and `ProxyCommand` are not the same thing.

Comment: Right, they are not, but this approach lets OP do what they say they want to do: set up one of the SSH connections in their `ssh_config` file to use the `-N` ssh flag, so they don't have to use `-N` every time they execute `ssh host`.